# Dynamically updating Cors Registry

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors

I have an application on heroku that return some oauth tokens. In my spring boot application I have used WebMvcConfigurerAdapter that gets a list of origin from database.

```
return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                String[] origins = new String[originList.size()];
                origins = originList.toArray(origins);
                registry.addMapping("/getToken").allowedHeaders("Allow-access-control-origin").allowedOrigins(origins);
            }
        };
```

Now, In the heroku app there is a text area where a user can update their domain name, user can add multiple domain. If a user wants to add multiple domain then the domain will be separated by comma and directly put in database. Later In the corsConfigurer() method i parse the domain names and get all the domain and white list it.

Everytime a user updates or add a domain then the server restarts to include all the changes.

**In spring or Java EE, Can i make cors registry to dynamically add updated or newly inserted origin in their whitelist registry without restarting the server.**

*(I searched on SO for this question but did not find any accepted answer)*

Thanks

Comment: nice question interested to know the outcomes and suggestions

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959114/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-update-a-list-of-allowed-origins-in-web-api-cors