# How do you update CORS origins while NodeJS server is running?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors

I am attempting to update the CORS origins while the NodeJS server is running. I am simply trying to overwrite the previous CORS configuration when a user makes a specific update.

I tried using `app.use(setCors(app.get('newCorsDomains')));`.

```
let setCors = (domains) => {    
  return cors({
    origin: domains
  });
};
```

I have confirmed I am sending the correct domains to this function, but the CORS origins do not seem to be getting updated when `app.use(setCors(app.get('newCorsDomains')));` is called.

Comment: You're updating it on the fly? `app.use()` typically only gets called the first time, you could create your own middleware that constructs and calls the cors() middleware on every call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to do this, but if you really do, probably your best bet would be to make a middleware function that wraps the cors middleware. It could look like this.

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  cors({ origin: app.get('newCorsDomains') })(req, res, next);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

It is possible but inadvisable.

### More details

Because Express's CORS middleware performs little to no [defensive copying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming), you can actually create a route that modifies the CORS configuration options.
Here is a proof of concept:

```js
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
}
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.post('/change-allowed-origin', function (req, res, next) {
  corsOptions.origin = 'http://attacker.com';
  res.send('Done!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

After starting the server locally:

```bash
$ curl -s -D - -o /dev/null -H "Origin: https://attacker.com" localhost:3000 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
Vary: Origin
-snip-

$ curl -XPOST localhost:3000/change-allowed-origin                          
Done!

$ curl -s -D - -o /dev/null -H "Origin: https://attacker.com" localhost:3000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://attacker.com
Vary: Origin
-snip-
```

However, I consider this a misfeature of Express's CORS middleware and I would discourage you from updating your CORS configuration on the fly. Because activating CORS amounts to relaxing security provided by default by the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy), any change to CORS configuration should instead be carefully reviewed and require a server restart.

Also, consider the risk of race conditions. What happens if you update the allowed origins during an invocation of the CORS middleware?

I'm curious as to why you'd want to update your CORS policy on the fly like that.
You should think twice (or thrice!) about it. And if you do end up allowing your CORS configuration to be updated on the fly, the route in question better require authorisation.